# Currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a TypeScript(TS), React project which I'm using to hold all my React components. I'm creating an NPM package out of this project which I'm then consuming in separate React projects. To solve a previous issue of .css and image files not being part of my package, I've now tried to implement Webpack but there are definite holes in my knowledge.

When trying to run webpack I get multiple similar errors:
`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.`

I've installed all the loaders that I understood to be necessary:

- style-loader
- ts-loader
- file-loader

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                ],
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@private_feed/generic.project",
  "version": "0.1.7",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.47",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.41",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.19",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App].",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem by trial and error. The webpack.config.js wasn't happy with two separate module sections.

Below is the config that resulted in a successful bundling.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure but it looks you override the `module` object on your webpack.config, if you have case with deep cloning of an object, you may use [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) or [webpack-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge).